# What is this vertex shader doing?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

I recently took over a project that was left stagnate a team member quit a few months ago.  While trying to get myself up to speed I came across this vertex shader and I'm having a hard time understanding what its doing:

```
uniform int axes;
varying vec4 passcolor;

void main()
{
  // transform the vertex
  vec4 point;
  if (axes == 0) {
     point = gl_Vertex;
  } else if (axes == 1) {
     point = gl_Vertex.xzyw;

  } else if (axes == 2) {
     point = gl_Vertex.xwzy;

  } else if (axes == 3) {
      point = gl_Vertex.yzxw;

  } else if (axes == 4) {
     point = gl_Vertex.ywxz;

  } else if (axes == 5) {
     point = gl_Vertex.zwxy;
  }

  point.z = 0.0;
  point.w = 1.0;

  // eliminate w point
  gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * point;

 passcolor = gl_Color;
}
```

The lines I'd like to better understand are the lines like this one:

```
point = gl_Vertex.xwzy;
```

I can't seem to find documentation that explains this.

Can someone give a quick explanation of what this shader is doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't seem to find documentation that explains this.

The [GLSL specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/) is pretty clear about how [swizzle selection](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Types#Swizzling) works.

What the shader is basically doing is an obtuse way of picking two axes from a `vec4`. Notice that the Z and W of the `point` are overwritten after the selection. By all rights, it could be rewritten as:

```
vec2 point;
if (axes == 0) {
   point = gl_Vertex.xy;
} else if (axes == 1) {
   point = gl_Vertex.xz;
} else if (axes == 2) {
   point = gl_Vertex.xw;
} else if (axes == 3) {
   point = gl_Vertex.yz;
} else if (axes == 4) {
   point = gl_Vertex.yw;
} else if (axes == 5) {
   point = gl_Vertex.zw;
}

gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(point.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
```

So it is just selecting two coordinates from the input vertex. Why it needs to do this, I can't say.

Answer (score 2):

The order of the x, y, z, and w after the . determines a mapping from the x, y, z and w of gl_Vertex to the x, y, z, and w of point.

This is called swizzling. `point = gl_Vertex` is equivalent to `point = gl_Vertex.xyzw`. `point = gl_Vertex.yxzw` results in a point equivalent to gl_Vertex with x and y values swapped.